# SharePoint 2013 Permissions

Tags: sharepoint

I break the inheritance in a subsite, and create group of permission has contribute permission level. Then add users to this group.

Now when i try to access the subsite by one of the users they are inside the group the message(Sorry this site hasn't shared with you).

Then, also i give the users Read Permission to the root site, because the template i used Publishing site, so now the users have 2 permissions one for the subsite and one for the root site (on page layout and master page).

and the message still appear to me !!

any one can help me?

Comment: Can you use the "Check Permissions" feature to ensure that they do indeed have permissions to the subsite, and what those are? Also, did you create a new permission level, or just a permission group?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're checking the permissions after you add them. Also make sure you're giving the user Read/Contribute permissions. 
Navigate to the page > hit the site settings button > select site permissions and verify that the link in your address bar is still pointing to your subsite.